# python, yaml how to parse a string containing apostrophe

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am using python to parse YAML files.

One of the YAML documents contain a dictionary such as follow:

```
scrapers:
    results: //article[@class='story ']
```

This apparently causes a problem because the last apostrophe is preceded by a whitespace. If I could remove the whitespace it would solve the problem. However since it is an xpath I can't.

Anyone knows how I could escape that sequence?
I looked into other SO question, but solution like wrapping the string in "", or 
using

```
scrapers:
  results: //article[@class='story ']
```

or

```
scrapers:>
  results: //article[@class='story ']
```

or

```
scrapers:
  results: //article[@class='story '']
```

did not work.

EDIT:
I am trying to open a file containing the above expression with:

```
import yaml
with open('/home/depot/wintergreen/yaml/scrapers.yml', 'r') as f:
    scrapers = yaml.load(f)
```

However i receive the error:
    ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

pointing at the whitespace after `story`.
I have been trying a suggestion offered by an answerer below, i.e. to create the yaml expression from a python dict. This works. I i save the yaml to file and load it back again it also does work.
However when i create the yaml by typing the exact same characters, then it does not work...

EDIT2:
I think the problem stemmed from the fact that i created the yaml file on a window machine and uploaded it on a unix server.

Comment: Where is the code that has a problem with this? What library do you use? Or are you trying to parse YAML with regular expressions? (You shouldn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to find the correct YAML format for a structure: create the structure in Python then use `yaml.dump` to create the YAML-encoded string:

```
d = {'scrapers': {'results': "//article[@class='story ']"}}
print d

import yaml
print yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=False)
```

The result of which is:

```
{'scrapers': {'results': "//article[@class='story '"}}

scrapers:
    results: //article[@class='story ']
```

That's the correct YAML representation, so if you're having a problem, it's with the parser, not the input text. If you use the standard `yaml` library it should parse fine.

Comment: There is no yaml parser in the standard Python library for any version of Python.

Comment: @Chris Johnson Yes you are right it works like that. My problem is that i have been trying to write the yaml (i.m on linux debian, with vim) and to load it in a python notebook using `import yaml
with open('/home/depot/wintergreen/yaml/scrapers.yml', 'r') as f:
    scrapers = yaml.load(f)`. There i receive an error that point at the whitespace after `story`:`ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here`. I tried to copy paste the yaml expression generated with your method into vim, and it still throw the same error. Maybe its a problem of encoding?

Comment: @Anthon are you making a distinction between library and standard library? `pip install pyyaml` followed by `import yaml` works well. This is a very common choice.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson `pyyaml`, although there is a multitude of reported problems, has effectively been unmaintained at least the last three years. Therefore I would not call that "the standard `yaml` library" as you do in your answer, which IMO would be an inappropriate recommendation.